# About android XML LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


    <AnalogClock 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <DigitalClock
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:textSize="14pt"
       android:gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why doesn't it help when I write  `android:gravity="bottom"`? The `DigitalClock` does not move and still stays the same place.

Comment: Post your full layout XML.

Comment: I posted,but the first line missed..I don't know why.

Comment: The first line is   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please indent code with four spaces to enable syntax highlighting. This time, I have done it for you :) This page might be interesting: [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @vankee i have answer to your question,please check once and let me know.

Comment: Explain what's not working. What do you expect gravity="bottom" to do?

Comment: the gravity is not working...not about the "bottom",the "right" or the "left" is ok as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working Fine:

For Digital clock you only set the gravity to the left, the Layoutgravity should be "left". and use  **android:gravity="left"**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <AnalogClock 
       android:id="@+id/analogClock1" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:gravity="center|top"/> 

  <DigitalClock 
      android:id="@+id/digitalClock1" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:paddingBottom="20dp" 
      android:text="DigitalClock" 
      android:gravity="center|bottom"/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Note:-Without gravity also digital clock working fine:

Comment: Really really don't know why..It's my first time using it .

Comment: no,i have checked in my local,it's working fine,you want seconds pin or minutes pin?

Comment: I just want to know how gravity works,but it seems doesn't work with the my xml.

Comment: = =...what kind of chat tool you use ..can you help me?

Comment: what?i did'n understand what u asking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79323/discussion-between-user-and-vankee).

Comment: I know ..the gravity is for all the element in the layout,not the single one.